# 400 bad-request error on parse-server api call node express

Tags: node.js, express, parse-server

I have a project with **backbone** as a fronted and **nodeJS,express parse-server** as a back end. Project is working perfectly in my local PC. but After deploying it on Linux server whenever i call
parse-server API it throws **400 bad request error**. also other post and get requests are working fine on server but only problem with that parse-server API.

**Bellow is my api server.js file**

```
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var router = express.Router();

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
    console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost. Shit!');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
  
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dp',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'xyz',
    //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'abc',
    
    serverURL: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1",
 
    maxUploadSize: '200mb',
    liveQuery: {
   
    },
   
    accountLockout: 
    {
        duration: 5, // duration policy setting determines the number of minutes that a locked-out account remains locked out before automatically becoming unlocked. Set it to a value greater than 0 and less than 100000.
        threshold: 3, // threshold policy setting determines the number of failed sign-in attempts that will cause a user account to be locked. Set it to an integer value greater than 0 and less than 1000.
    },
    sessionLength:18000
   
});

var app = express();

  app.use( function (req, res, next) 
  {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

    next();
});

var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/api/v1';

app.use(mountPath, api);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

I am calling api **http://IP:port/api/v1/login**. in my local its working perfect but on linux server its throwing 400 bad request error.

I am using pm2 to start my service on linux server.

Comment: Do you see any relevant message on your Parse Server logs?

Comment: there is no any error logs in "pm2 logs".

Comment: Have you tried to turn parse-server verbose option on?

Comment: I just turned it on then checked it. its not giving any logs except "verbose: Support key pairs Map {}".

Comment: How is your deployment? Do you have a reverse proxy or any other thing on top of parse server/pm2?

Comment: Yes, i am using proxy request logic at front end server to call api from back end node server. its like 

"location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
}"

Comment: I guess that's the one with setup problem. If you try a request from inside the machine directly to pme, does it work?

Comment: Yes, I just reinstalled NodeJs with latest version and issue resolved. Thanks for your help